# how to remove _id from create replay mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, projection

```
exports.createDD_PR_addresstype = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  const dropdowns = await DD_PR_addresstype.create(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: dropdowns
  });
});
```

replay

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "_id": "5f252a444824ac0164195c1a",
        "label": "Battery",
        "company_id": "5f17e0f4d6eded0db090b272",
        "value": 1,
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

i want to show only label and value. is there is any pre functions available to select created replay or i have to use seperate find query

Answer (score 1):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the query response:

```
const { label, value } = await DD_PR_addresstype.create(req.body);

res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  data: { label, value }
});
```

But that's just a way to write less code for:

```
data: {
  value: dropdowns.value,
  label: dropdowns.label
}
```

---

If you're looking for retrieving the document later with only the given props then the `projection` answer (which was deleted in between) is the way to go.

Since the other [`projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) answer was deleted I add it here (using `_id` just as example):

```
const dropdowns = await DD_PR_addresstype.find( { _id: "5f252a444824ac0164195c1a" }, { label: 1, value: 1 } )
```

Comment: yeah the second method i did it for now but if the json replay body has many fields can i remove just one or two fields like selecting _id and remove it is possilbe?

Comment: like this? `const dropdowns = await DD_PR_addresstype.find( { _id: "5f252a444824ac0164195c1a" }, { _id: 0  } )` . This will return all props except `_id`

Comment: yeah in create method without calling second find query with id

Comment: I don't think you can use `projection` during create directly. But you could define a custom instance method for the Schema which saves your document and  returns only the needed props. I'm not an expert there may also be other ways. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585080/how-to-add-schema-method-in-mongoose)